# Is it okay to handle Runtime exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

It's generally a good practice to not handle runtime exceptions.

I have this scenario :

```
  /**boolean returns false if the method execution fails,
  so that an error can be shown to user*/ 
boolean saveData()
 {
    try
    {
         //Some database calls that throw only Runtime exceptions
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         //Log the exception and return false
         return false;
     }
     return true;

 }
```

So from the Servlet calling it will get a boolean value. If it's false, we show a message 'Save Not sucessful'. Is this okay or is there a better way of doing it ?

Comment: Why not let your caller method(client) to handle the exception rather than `saveData`

Comment: Because they are runtime exceptions. We don't really know in advance what kind of exceptions the framework throws.

Comment: IMO you have to log exception at top level, in the client exception and also handle the exception at that level.

Comment: what you're doing there is a bad design on several levels. There are sometimes reasons for catching runtime exceptions, but generally these should be prevented every way possible and then, if you are catching runtime exceptions, catch them to be logged or transformed to a different kind of exception.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it okay to handle Runtime exceptions?

As long as you can do something intelligent at that point, yes.  This 'never catch run-time exceptions' is pure nonsense.  You'll probably want to log them and do other things, as well.

Answer (score 5):

> It's generally a good practice to not handle runtime exceptions.

This sentence implies a false premise: the question is not *whether*, but *when* to catch runtime exceptions.

At some point in your code you should definitely have a "catch-all" exception handler. This point is called the *exception barrier*, and it is high enough in the call stack to encompass a complete *unit of work* (basically, the scope of one database transaction).

This should be your governing principle:

- if an exception must cause the current unit of work to be aborted (rolled back), then *do not catch that exception* until the exception barrier;
- if an exception is of local character only, and its appearance only means taking a different route to the handling of the request, then *do* catch and handle it early.

Note that the above doesn't use the fruitless checked/unchecked distinction. Most modern frameworks completely avoid checked exceptions and go out of their way to shield the programmer from such exceptions being thrown from lower-level code.

In practice, more than 90% of all exceptions are of the first, aborting kind. This is what is meant by the term "unrecoverable"—it means you can't continue what you are doing right now, but the server can stay up and process all other requests. I see many people confusing this with "the JVM is about to die", but exceptions which have that meaning are exceedingly rare and usually there is no special handling code for them.

Lastly, note that the "catch-all" handler should catch not only `RuntimeExceptions` but also `Error`s because you want *every* exception logged the same way. If you let an exception escape your application code, there is no knowing what behavior it will cause. Note that there are some common errors, like StackOverflow and OutOfMemory, which can *in principle* cause unrecoverable damage and therefore rightfully belong to the `Error` hierarchy, yet *in most real-life cases* do no damage beyond aborting the current request. You definitely do not want to shut down your service at the first sight of such an error.

Comment: The checked/unchecked distinction is "almost" a good thing; it *would* be a good thing code that calls a method which is declared as throwing a checked exception could declaratively specify that it is not *expected* to throw such an exception [even if the calling method is declared as throwing that same exception], and any such exception it does throw should be considered "unexpected" and re-thrown wrapped in an unchecked exception.  If `foo()`, which throws (checked) `BarException` calls `moo()`, and `moo()`, despite being declared as throwing `BarException`, isn't expected to...

Comment: ...have conditions arise which would result in it being thrown, then a `BarException` which gets thrown from within `moo()` should probably not be caught by code which wants to catch any `BarException`s thrown by `foo`.  BTW, are you being facetious when calling `OutOfMemory` "innocuous"?

Comment: I was thinking in the same direction---some mechanism whereby you can opt out of being molested by checked exceptions---but autowrapping of checked exceptions doesn't seem like the right way to me. Wrapping itself is kind of a hack already: what it *should* be about is adapting the callee's exception to the caller's API, but this applies to checked and unchecked exceptions alike. I really don't see what *danger* lies behind exceptions being unchecked---after all, a bug concerning an uhnandled exception is the very easiest bug to fix.

Comment: @supercat As for OOME, I wasn't facetious. Although it certainly is true that there are unrecoverable OOME's, most of them are of the benign, recoverable variety, and the unwinding of the call stack causes the essential GC roots to be freed.

Comment: My Java experience is limited, but if an OOME occurs how certain can one be that cleanups performed by using-with-resources have actually been performed, and that once the stack is unwound any pools of "emergency memory" space will be restocked?

Comment: All the cleanup will be done regardless of which exception was thrown because they happen in `finally` blocks---not even a `ThreadDeath` exception will disturb this. And there's no need for "emergency memory"---once the stack has been unwound, memory has automatically been freed because all the objects allocated while processing the request have become unreachable. Do take into account that I am describing the *typical* case there---yes, it is certainly *possible* to lock in all that memory, but it is not usual.

Comment: If an OOME occurs while trying to allocate a small object (implying that there really isn't much memory available), and the `finally` method needs to allocate a little memory, what happens if that allocation doesn't succeed?  Once things have unwound a few levels they'll probably be okay, but what happens on those first levels?  Is there any way the caller can tell which `finally` methods ran to completion?

Comment: No, and that is not the only bad scenario: the OOME may happen in the middle of manipulating a durable memory structure; it may happen in another thread, which isn't causing heap exhaustion, but whose continuous operation is key to system stability, and so on. SOE similarly has the potential for a disaster. The point is, most of the time this stuff *doesn't* happen and you don't want to throw your hands into the air at the first sign of *potential, unlikely* trouble and bring the whole system down. Also note that "bringing the system down" has a much higher potential of causing damage.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42362/discussion-between-supercat-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 3):

No, catching a general `Exception` will mask any other problems you don't want to catch. Better catching specific exceptions making it harder for unexpected ones to go missing.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your question has two aspects: 1) Handling `RuntimeException`as the heading suggested and 2) handling generic `Exception` these are two different things.

[The Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) of `RuntimeExcepton` list a bunch of its subclasses (`NullPointerException`..etc). If you look carefully, these are nothing but the **programming errors** and instead of handling them in `catch` block, **should be corrected** the the code itself so that they do not occur.

Handling generic `Exception` is generally referred as a poor practice and rightly so because **it hides the specific exceptions** which might need different handling.

But in case similar to yours, if there is a Servlet giving a call to method there has to be a graceful way to tell the user that there was some problem with the application while processing the request instead if showing the stacktrace.

So what you are doing could be one way of handling and as a good practice keep track of errors/exceptions in the log and correct any `RuntimeException`s

Comment: Many exception types that are used by various classes derive from `RuntimeException` because there's no other nice way in Java to identify exceptions which *some* overrides of a method may be expected to throw, and which other overrides never will, and which some callers will expect to handle directly and others will not.  Code which wants to catch such exceptions should preferably catch those it expects, rather than every `RuntimeException`, but the fact that such exceptions derive from `RuntimeException` shouldn't dissuade one from catching them.

Answer (score 1):

> boolean returns false if the method execution **fails**,
>     so that an **error** can be shown to user

This is a clear reason for the method to throw an exception.  It is why the exception mechanism exists in the first place.  Best practice is to use exceptions for these types of circumstances, not boolean signals.

Anytime you follow this kind of pattern, you suffer in several ways

- The caller cannot be sure what really happened.  Was there a communication failure?  Was the data corrupted?  There is no way to tell when you return a simple "FAILED" signal.
- Because the caller cannot know what happened, you take away options for the caller.  Maybe the caller could do something in certain error cases.
- You increase the potential for data errors.  Again, since the caller cannot know why it failed, the caller may make assumptions about why it failed and continue in cases when the entire program should halt.  If the program continues, it may decide to process invalid data when it really should stop.

I highly recommend reading the sections on exception handling in *Effective Java*.  Basically, if you can't do anything meaningful with an Exception in your method, you should allow it to pass up the stack.  **In the worst case scenario**, the API you reference throws a generic checked exception, giving you one of three choices (EDIT:  *Changed to `void` return type because the boolean return type no longer has any meaning -- you either succeed or throw an exception*)

-Create your own.

```
 // "MyFatalException" would be a checked Exception 
 public void saveData() throws MyFatalException{
        try{
           // ... do stuff that throws Exception
        }catch(Exception e){
           throw new MyFatalException("Unable to save Data due to a general exception"+
                                      " thrown by foo.bar()", e);
        }
 }
```

-Throw an existing type (*my preference is for subclasses of RuntimeException*)

```
public void saveData() throws IllegalStateException{
        try{
           // ... do stuff that throws Exception
        }catch(Exception e){
           throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to save Data due to a general exception"+
                                      " thrown by foo.bar()", e);
        }
```

-Declare to throw a generic Exception and let it pass up (I do NOT recommend this, but you'll see many developers who do this)

```
 public void saveData() throws Exception{
       // no try/catch needed.  Just make the call
 }
```

Comment: Your last choice demonstrates how checked exceptions result in leaky abstractions---you had to change the interface of your method just because the code you call internally throws some checked exceptions. And that's not all---now all the callers of your method must change *their* interface. It's like the poison pill.

Answer (score 0):

The general concept is that frameworks or APIs would throw a RuntimeException only in situations when the error is not recoverable in code. e.g: your Db is down, or your server socket is down and things like that.
Though its not bad to catch such exceptions but whats actually thoughtful is what do you intend to do after catching them. e.g: people prefer to catch DB level connection problems and errors which are runtime exception subclasses and show error pages on their websites. Checked exceptions are usually for code level situational cases and catching them and handling is what code is expected to do.

Comment: All modern frameworks go out of their way to shield the programmer from the drudgery of handling checked exceptions.

Comment: @Marko no they do not. they just provide a way so that we dont have to handle non recoverable situational based runtime errors and exceptions. Am not sure what you mean by "handling checked exceptions" in your comment.

Comment: You said an unchecked exception is non-recoverable, whereas Spring, Hibernate, and many others specifically turn JDK's checked exceptions into unchecked ones. Therefore you claim that they turn recoverable into unrecoverable errors.

Comment: actually what i meant was the intent of throwing unchecked exception by such frameworks is that they are non recoverable. The point i was making is that non recoverable situations are indicated in majority by unchecked exceptions. hibernate and spring are two big examples. spring's exception translator has this as one of its primary purposes.

Comment: Spring declares *no checked exceptions whatsoever*. Do you claim that no exceptions whatsoever thrown by Spring are recoverable?

Comment: i really don't know what you are reading in my comments that makes you believe that i am saying that "spring throws checked exceptions". In my last comment i explicitly said "throwing unchecked exception by such frameworks is that they are non recoverable". This surely means that i am saying spring does throw unchecked exceptions in its ORM wrappers. Spring does use exception translators to wrap the checked underlying platform exceptions into unchecked DataAccessException and like wise. Anyway i give up. maybe its my English thats causing complications here.

Comment: You don't claim that Spring throws checked exceptions; you claim that *all unchecked exceptions are unrecoverable*. Combined with the fact that Spring throws nothing *but* unchecked exceptions, it follows that you claim "All exceptions thrown by Spring are unrecoverable".

Comment: Let me give you a specifically poignant example: [`org.springframework.dao.RecoverableDataAccessException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/RecoverableDataAccessException.html). It is an *unchecked* exception.

Comment: ok. What i meant was "an unrecoverable situation is indicated largely by an unchecked exception  being thrown but not always" I understand now you read it the other way round. You are right in your understand about Spring and hbm. and that was exactly what i was trying to convey. I was talking in a general case. Ofocurse it wont cover all 100% scenarios.

Comment: When it comes to state-of-the art frameworks, this is the truth: *checked exceptions do not even exist*. For almost a whole decade they have been categorized as a failure of language design, causing boilerplate code, leaky abstractions, errors resulting from broken exception handling patterns, and so on.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: IMHO, checked exceptions could probably be made into a good thing with a couple of language changes, centering a "doesntcatch" declaration which would cause any exceptions which meet the specification, are thrown *from within nested methods*, and are not otherwise caught, to be caught and wrapped in an UnexpectedCheckedException [derived from RuntimeException].  This could for normal method calls be supported entirely in the compiler.  The only major difficulty I could see would be with constructors.

Comment: If a base class constructor can throw a particular checked exception, I'm not sure the JVM would allow the constructor of a derived class to wrap that exception in its own (since from what I understand the JVM restricts what can happen around a chained constructor call, and I think `try` blocks are among the things restricted).

Answer (score 0):

In case you try something like this, since you don't want your users to error page you can do this, provided you caught all other exceptions before this.

```
boolean saveData()
 {
    try
    {
         //Some database calls that throw only Runtime exceptions
     }catch(db_Connectivity_Exception e){
         //exception like credentials invalid
     }catch(db_table_Exception e){
         //table desc. changed
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         //Log the exception and return false
         //Since you are going to log your error I hope is not harmfu
         return false;
     }
     return true;

 }
```

Still this is not best practice